# How to resolve - error: there are no arguments to 'exit' that depend on a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, exit

As the question makes clear, I am working with templates, a template class to be precise. The code in question is found within a public member function of the template class and is a simple `exit(1);` command. The error message produced is `error: there are no arguments to ‘exit’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘exit’ must be available [-fpermissive]`. I am only getting this error after compiling using g++ 4.8.1, 4.2.1 did not produce this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `<stdlib.h>` or `<cstdlib>` (and use `std::exit`). It worked previously because the previous compiler probably had that header included implicitly by a different header.

Comment: Sure enough, that was it. Oddly enough, I finally found the solution online in a forum in French. Thank you. Hopefully this makes it easier for others to find this solution.